# How can I configurer BIND named to return a local IP rather than a public IP for internal users?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I have setup a BIND named server and I am trying to figure out how to get it to return a local IP, rather than a public IP, for a handful of servers that we have.

Here's an example of what the name server currently returns:

secure.example.com -> 1.2.3.4 (public IP)

What I would like for it to return:

secure.example.com -> 192.168.20.10 (internal IP)

How would I go about configuring this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You have to use views in bind. Look down in the split DNS section

http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/view.html

It allows you to create a view based on IP subnets where you can say this view should resolve using this file and this other view should resolve with this file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use  [views](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/view.html), you create ACLs based on networks, that list who should receive replies of private or public IPs.